# Related Posts with removing some categories

Tags: wp-query, single

Hi I have a main category which is "Anime" and three sub-categories which is "On going" - "Completed" - "Future" ( also there's other categories too ).
I'm using this code to show related posts on **single.php**:

```
<div class="sixteen wide column recommendationss" style="display:none;padding-top: 0px;">
    <div class="ui master table">
        <div class="body two-cells">
<?php
    $related = get_posts( array( 'category__in' => wp_get_post_categories($post->ID), 'numberposts' => 5, 'post__not_in' => array($post->ID) ) );
    if( $related ) foreach( $related as $post ) {
    setup_postdata($post); ?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell cover">
                    <div class="ui lazy loaded" style="padding-bottom: 145.33%;">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="cell info">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> 
                    <small><?php the_field('archivyear'); ?></small>
                </div>
            </div>
    <?php }
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

so how can I remove those four categories from this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`category__not_in`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) parameter to exlude categories.

[`get_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/) uses the [`WP_QUERY`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters) parameters

Your code will be :

```
$related = get_posts( array( 
               'category__in' => wp_get_post_categories($post->ID),
               'numberposts' => 5, 
               'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
               'category__not_in' => array(1,2,3,4)'
          ) );
```